# Creating websocket Java APIs

Tags: java, api, websocket

I want to create a websocket Java API for these requirements:
"When the user logs into my application, if he enters a page which has constant updates from the server, then the Java API should identify the user and keep pushing the contents on a regular interval"

So for this I want to get started in creating a generic Java API so that for other pages, which requires push from server, I can use the APIs instead of reinventing the wheel everytime

What are the things I should take into consideration and how should I approach this problem

Please key in your thoughts

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are working inside tomcat you can checkout the newly(not finished) [websocket implementation in 7.0.27](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub has a number of libraries which deal with Java and WebSocket. You can build your application on top of one of them. Examples are [vert.x](https://github.com/purplefox/vert.x), [SockJS](https://github.com/cgbystrom/sockjs-netty), [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) etc.

At the [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client) page you can see a list of clients/servers for working with it. 
IMHO It is better to re-use one of the existing libraries/frameworks than building your own, because yours is a common usecase and working with web sockets, providing corss browser compatibility etc are not trivial as of now.